# EWS api throwing exception "Internal Server Error"

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am using the below code to send a reply but I am getting exception *An internal server error occurred. The operation failed* on `SendAndSaveCopy()`:

```
EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id);
email.Load();
ResponseMessage reply = email.CreateReply(email.ReplyTo.Count > 1 ? true : false);
string data = email.Subject.Split(':')[1].Trim();
reply.BodyPrefix = CreateHtmlBodyForReplyMail(email.From.Address, Convert.ToInt32(email.Subject.Split(':')[1].Trim()), message, status);
reply.SendAndSaveCopy(); // Exception is in this line
```

Stacktrace:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ProcessWebException(WebException webException) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 995
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 831
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 724
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute() in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\SimpleServiceRequestBase.cs:line 40
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest1.Execute() in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\MultiResponseServiceRequest.cs:line 157
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateResponseObject(ServiceObject responseObject, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable 1 messageDisposition) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ExchangeService.cs:line 71
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ResponseObject 1.InternalCreate(FolderId destinationFolderId, MessageDisposition messageDisposition) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ServiceObjects\ResponseObjects\ResponseObject.cs:line 86
at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ResponseObject 1.SendAndSaveCopy() in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ServiceObjects\ResponseObjects\ResponseObject.cs:line 156
at MailingService.Common.MailBLL.SendReply(Item item, String message, String status) in c:\Users\fahad.r\Desktop\MailingService\MailingService.Common\BLL\MailBLL.cs:line 124
at MailingService.Common.MailBLL.SyncMail() in c:\Users\fahad.r\Desktop\MailingService\MailingService.Common\BLL\MailBLL.cs:line 87`
```

If I use another account to send and receive mails but with the same domain, it works fine.

What do I have to change?

Comment: Enable tracing in the managedAPI, then look at the reply from the server. Usually there is more information in that than the exceptions tell you.

Comment: Can you please guide me with some more information? I mean how do I enable tracing and how do I know the response from the server.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495632%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx